# webpack browserify --ignore equivalent?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, browserify

I have some code that doesn't work in the browser unless I "ignore" two packages, I can do this fine with browserify: `browserify files.js -i fs-extra -i request --standalone files > files.browserify.js`, the resulting code just works, but if I try to do it with webpack the code complains about modules being missing.

```
...
  plugins: [
      new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/fs-extra$/),
      new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/request$/),
      new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/fs$/)
  ],
...
```

---

```
test.webpack.js:7655 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "request"
    at webpackMissingModule (test.webpack.js:7655)
    at Object.exports.byteLength (test.webpack.js:7655)
    at __webpack_require__ (test.webpack.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (test.webpack.js:17012)
    at __webpack_require__ (test.webpack.js:20)
    at test.webpack.js:66
    at test.webpack.js:69
```

I suspect that maybe webpack doesn't create an "empty stub" like browserify does: `--ignore, -i  Replace a file with an empty stub. Files can be globs.`.

What can I do to fix this?

### Resources

- https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-for-browserify-users.html#ignore
- https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#ignoreplugin

Comment: Not sure, but maybe check https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#target ?

Comment: I upvoted, because I've got a similar problem. But I noticed, that the error message refers to `require` not being defined. That sounds like a different can of worms.

Comment: @Boldewyn ah, wrong error message, I've updated the post, the `require` error message came when I as experimenting with target: 'node', target: 'web', etc, it now refers to `Cannot find module "request"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is `null-loader` which returns an empty module:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /^(fs-extra|fs|request)$/,
            loader: "null"
        },
        ...
]
```

To install:

```
$ npm i -D null-loader
```

Comment: In Webpack 2: replace `loaders` by `rules`, and write `null-loader` instead of `null`.